# neighbors of vertex w

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I saw this question in my textbook:
If a vertex w is part of a simple and connected graph H, then vertex w must have a neighbor in each of the components of graph H-w.

Now my attempt: if we suppose that graph H is a simple connected graph then the vertices in one component of H – w must have paths in H to every
other component of H – w, but a path can only leave a component of H – w using this vertex w.
Did i prove this completely?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In some component of $H-w$ pick a vertex, and join it to $w$ by a minimum length path in $H$. Now what will that path look like?

Comment: an edge? @Lord Shark the Unknown

Comment: @mandella Only if you've picked a vertex adjacent to $w$; what if you don't?

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Isn't it enough to say that without w, the components in H cannot be connected otherwise? @Lord Shark the Unknown